# Работа с элементами XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Допустим у меня есть XML:

```
<root>
<node attr1="" attr2="" attr3="">
Text
</node> 
</root>
```

и мне нужно считать значение каждого атрибута в определенную переменную.

Сейчас я прохожу в цикле foreach по всем атрибутам, а потом с помощью трёх if я анализирую имя и присваиваю значение атрибута своей переменной.

Подскажите, есть ли более лаконичное решение этой задачи?

Ведь если мне потребуется считывать больше атрибутов, то мне придется плодить дополнительные if...

Comment: В нормальной ситуации вам не должно хотеться разложить атрибуты по отдельным переменным. Если вы расскажете, для чего это вам, возможно, подойдёт другая идея.

Comment: Файл XML у меня является неким скриптом. Каждый Node у меня является действием, а аттрибут описанием действия(Name,Type,Action). Я считываю данные в List<T>, а потом на основании этих действий, программа выполняет некоторую работу. Как-то так.

Comment: Окей, понял. А не нужна ли вам случайно _десериализация_?

Comment: Возможно, это хороший вариант, но я с ней не разу не работал-(

Comment: Добавил решение с десериализацией

Comment: А вы можете привести пример своих if для атрибутов? И что означают атрибуты name, type и action?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Например, можно так:

```
var s = "<root><node attr1=\"\" attr2=\"\" attr3=\"\">Text</node></root>";
var doc = XDocument.Parse(s);
foreach (var node in doc.Descendants("node"))
{
    foreach (var attr in node.Attributes())
        Console.WriteLine("Name = {0}, Value = {1}", attr.Name, attr.Value);
}
```

Или если вам нужно собрать все атрибуты в один объект, то так:

```
var attrDict = node.Attributes().ToDictionary(attr => attr.Name, attr => attr.Value);
foreach (var kvp in attrDict)
    Console.WriteLine(kvp);
```

Если вы хотите проверить какой-то отдельный атрибут, это делается так:

```
var attr1 = node.Attribute("attr1");
if (attr1 != null)
{
    string attr1Value = attr1.Value;
    // ...
}
```

---

С учётом комментариев, возможно, вам подойдёт такое решение:

Описываем структуру данных как сериализируемую:

```
// так называется узел в XML
[XmlRoot("node")]
public class Animal
{
    // так называется атрибут в XML
    [XmlAttribute("length")]
    public int Length { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("color")]
    public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

Сама десериализация:

```
var s = "<root><node length=\"10\" name=\"Eeyore\" color=\"gray\">Text</node></root>";
var doc = XDocument.Parse(s);

var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Animal));
foreach (var node in doc.Descendants("node"))
{
    var animal = (Animal)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(node.CreateReader());
    // ...
}
```

Обратите внимание, что десериализатор сконвертировал для вас строку `"10"` в `int`.

Учтите, что десериализация сложна и налагает свои требования. Например, мне *пришлось* объявить класс `Animal` как public, и сделать свойства доступными для записи. Поэтому решение с десериализацией, возможно, не самое подходящее.

Comment: А для чего вы используете `XDocument.Parse` и `XmlSerializer` совместно? Вам это не кажется странным десериализовывать документ по частям?

Comment: @pavelip: Нет, автор ведь не расписал структуру остальной части XML-документа. XDocument чтобы легко переходить между частями, XmlSerializer для собственно десериализации. Полностью отказаться от XDocument можно было бы, если бы было гарантировано, что весь документ представляет собой сериализированную структуру. Наоборот, если в нём есть «лишние» данные, пришлось бы писать ненужные пустые классы только для того, чтобы десериализировать их и выкинуть.

Comment: @pavelip: Вам, в свою очередь, не кажется странным, что у `Deserialize` есть перегрузка с `XmlReader`'ом?

Comment: С "лишними данными" XmlSerializer справляется отлично - он их спокойно пропускает. Про перегрузку не кажется странным :)

Comment: @pavelip: Под «лишними» данными я имею в виду, например, узел `<root/>`, а не данные _внутри_ `<node/>`. Как вы объясните XmlSerializer'у, что надо под root'ом найти все узлы node и десериализовать их? Может я чего-нибудь не знаю — покажите код лучше. (Код в вашем ответе создаёт лишний узел для root. Если в реальном xml такой лишней информации много, вам придётся создавать много фиктивных классов.)

Comment: Фиктивные классы придется создавать только для иерархии. Сами они могут быть пустыми. На мой взгляд, чаще используются все данные из документа в одном месте - при первичной обработке. Следовательно нужен весь документ с его объектной моделью. Да, и к тому же в вопросе формат документа был достаточно простой. Могу заметить, что сериализатор не очень будет хорошо рабоать с большими xml документами...

Comment: @pavelip: (1) Вот именно. Придётся создавать. Моё решение избегает этого несколькими строчками кода. (2) Не уверен, что этот XML-документ представляет собой действительно какую-то объектную модель. (3) Ну и в примере явно упрощённый формат, я бы не закладывался на то, что реальный формат настолько прост. (4) Для больших документов можно всё читать XmlReader'ом (только код будет сложнее), а десериализировать таки через XmlSerializer. Это проще, чем вычитывать атрибуты вручную по одному.

Comment: @VladD, а если в узле есть еще один узел, то придется делать foreach в foreach?

Comment: @iluxa1810: Смотря от того, каким вариантом решения вы пользуетесь. Если вам нужны _только_ внутренние узлы, вы можете выбрать их при помощи `Descendants`, стартуя от корня.

Comment: @VladD,допустим в вашем примере внутри класса Animal будет еще 1 корневой класс с несколькими атрибутами. Как будет происходить считывание всех атрибутов в таком случае?

Comment: @iluxa1810: Для решения через `foreach` — через вложенный `foreach`. Для решения с десериализацией это будет происходить автоматически, т. к. десериализация умеет обрабатывать не только свойства простых типов, но и вложенные объекты.

Answer (score 1):

**Вариант 1**

Сериализовать можно сразу весь xml документ:

```
const string XmlString = 
    "<root>" +
        "<node attr1=\"1\" attr2=\"mystr1\" attr3=\"true\">Text1</node>" +
        "<node attr1=\"2\" attr2=\"mystr2\" attr3=\"false\">Text2</node>" + 
    "</root>";

TaskRoot root;
var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TaskRoot));
using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(XmlString))
{
    root = (TaskRoot)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
}

foreach (var node in root.Nodes)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3}", node.Attr1, node.Attr2, node.Attr3, node.Text);
}
```

Для этого потребуется описать объектное представление xml документа:

```
[XmlRoot("root")]
public class TaskRoot
{
    [XmlElement("node")]
    public List<TaskNodeRoot> Nodes { get; set; }
}

public class TaskNodeRoot
{
    // так называется атрибут в XML
    [XmlAttribute("attr1")]
    public int Attr1 { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("attr2")]
    public string Attr2 { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("attr3")]
    public bool Attr3 { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Вывод будет такой:

```
1 mystr1 True Text1
2 mystr2 False Text2
```

**Вариант 2**

Можно упростить код и написать отдельный helper-класс:

```
public static class XmlSerializerEx
{
    public static T Deserialize<T>(string xmlString)
    {
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xmlString))
        {
            return (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
}
```

Тогда код будет выглядеть так:

```
var root = XmlSerializerEx.Deserialize<TaskRoot>(XmlString);
```