# Конверсия с xml в Excel

Tags: c#, .net, excel

Имею xml файл подобного содержания:

```
<Placemark>
    <name>Company name</name>
    <description>Some description</description>
    <styleUrl>#icon-503-DB4436</styleUrl>
    <ExtendedData>
        <Data name='opis'>
            <value> Som desc.</value>
        </Data>
        <Data name='Informacje:'>
            <value> Some information</value>
        </Data>
        <Data name='Telefon:'>
            <value> (22) 333 55 55 (22); (22) 333 44 44</value>
        </Data>
        <Data name='E-mail'>
            <value> qwerty@mail.com</value>
        </Data>
        <Data name='Strona:'>
            <value> www.google.com </value>
        </Data>
        <Data name='gx_media_links'>
            <value>some links</value>
        </Data>
    </ExtendedData>
    <Point>
        <coordinates>22.912227,52.12221,0.0</coordinates>
    </Point>
</Placemark>
<Placemark>
    <name>Company name 2</name>
    <description>Some description 2</description>
    <styleUrl>#icon-503-DB4436</styleUrl>
    <ExtendedData>
        <Data name='opis'>
            <value> Som desc. 2</value>
        </Data>
        <Data name='Informacje:'>
            <value> Some information 2 </value>
        </Data>
        <Data name='Telefon:'>
            <value> (22) 555 55 55 (22); (22) 444 44 44</value>
        </Data>
        <Data name='E-mail'>
            <value> 12345@mail.com</value>
        </Data>
        <Data name='Strona:'>
            <value> www.yandex.com </value>
        </Data>
        <Data name='gx_media_links'>
            <value>some links 2</value>
        </Data>
    </ExtendedData>
    <Point>
        <coordinates>22.913337,52.13331,0.0</coordinates>
    </Point>
</Placemark>
```

После прохода программы (скрипта) должен получится файл, для редактирования в MS Excel, следующего вида:
[image: Result]
.

Пока накидал примитивный код, но не выходит отобразить в разных ячейках содержимое, к примеру Data name='Informacje:'.../Data.

```
class AddressComponent
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string styleUrl { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
    public string coordinates { get; set; }

    public List<string> type { get; set; }

    public AddressComponent()
    {
        type = new List<string>();
    }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
    xml.Load("C:\\2.xml");

    XmlNodeList nodeList = xml.GetElementsByTagName("Placemark");

    List<AddressComponent> listAddress = new List<AddressComponent>();
    foreach (XmlNode e in nodeList)
    {
        AddressComponent temp = new AddressComponent();
        temp.name = e.ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText;
        temp.description = e.ChildNodes.Item(1).InnerText;
        temp.styleUrl = e.ChildNodes.Item(2).InnerText;
        temp.Data = e.ChildNodes.Item(3).InnerText;
        temp.coordinates = e.ChildNodes.Item(4).InnerText;

        for (int i = 1; i < e.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
        {
            temp.type.Add(e.InnerText);
        }

        listAddress.Add(temp);
    }

    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\1.csv", false, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        foreach (var e in listAddress)
        {
            sw.WriteLine("\"{0}\"; \"{1}\"; \"{2}\"; \"{3}\"; \"{4}\"",
                e.name, e.description, e.styleUrl, e.Data, e.coordinates);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вариант 1**

Вы можете сериализовать Xml-документ через [XmlSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) в объект своего пользовательского класса. Пример работы с `XmlSerializer` можно посмотреть [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/444148/184661).

Потом взять любую библиотеку для работы с Excel ([OpenXml](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/), [NPOI](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NPOI/) или напрямую [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel(v=office.15).aspx)). Хорошая [статья](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/office/cc861607.aspx) по работе с OpenXml.

В цикле прогнать ваше преобразование.

**Вариант 2**

Преобразовать ваш xml-документ в текстовый файл в формате `csv` с разделителями `;`. Excel понимает этот формат и его можно будет открыть для редактирования.

Сам же xml-документ можно обработать через [XDocument.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.parse(v=vs.110).aspx).

**UPDATE**

```
class AddressComponent
{
    //...

    public Dictionary<string, string> ExtendedData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
}

//...

temp.coordinates = e.ChildNodes.Item(4).InnerText;

foreach (XmlNode item in e["ExtendedData"])
{
    var attr = item.Attributes["name"].Value;
    var val = item.InnerText;
    temp.ExtendedData.Add(attr, val);
}

listAddress.Add(temp);

//...

using (var sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\1.csv", false, Encoding.Default))
{
    foreach (var e in listAddress)
    {
        sw.WriteLine("\"{0}\"; \"{1}\"; \"{2}\"; \"{3}\"; \"{4}\"; \"{5}\";\"{6}\";\"{7}\"\r\n",
            e.name, e.description, e.styleUrl, e.Data, e.value, 
            e.coordinates, e.ExtendedData["Informacje"],
            e.ExtendedData.ContainsKey("gx_media_links")?e.ExtendedData["gx_media_links"]:"");
    }
}
```

Comment: Пока, как начинающему, это будет сложно, но спасибо за наводку.

Comment: @IgKos пробуйте и приходите с более конкретными вопросами ;) Так же добавил второй вариант решения задачи.

Comment: Суть в том, что потом надо будет реализовать конверсию обратно в xml файл, который должен интегрироваться с google maps. И эта обратная конверсия для меня вообще дремучий лес, поэтому хочу правильно подойти к первому этапу, чтобы самому себе не придумать проблем на втором.

Comment: В обоих вариантах обратное преобразование будет таки же как и прямое.

Comment: Мне бы очень здорово помог код, особенно в части записи значения в определенную ячейку листа Excel.

Comment: @IgKos Добавил ссылочку по работе с Excel через OpenXml.

Comment: Пошел по пути с csv. Но не выходит отобразить в разных ячейках содержимое <Data name='opis'>, <Data name='Telefon:'>, <Data name='Informacje:'>...</Data> и т.д., оно все в одной ячейке. Знаю, что проблема в "public string Data { get; set; }" но не знаю как исправить.

Comment: @IgKos Обновил ответ. В файл должно выводится поле `Informacje`. Остальные аналогично...

Comment: @IgKos только с csv аккуратнее. В примере содержимое ячеек заэскейплено кавычками -- это спасет от того, что в ячейке содержится разделитель. Но не спасет, если в ячейке есть двойная кавычка -- ее надо удваивать. Лучше использовать нормальную библиотеку (например, CsvHelper) для корректной конвертации.

Comment: Да, все работает исправно, спасибо. Но столкнулся с практической проблемой: в xml документе не в каждом блоке есть тег <Data name='gx_media_links'>...</Data> и скрипт вылетает ошибкой. Как обойти подобную проблему?

Comment: @IgKos Проверить item на null в foreach

Comment: Очень просил бы Вас помочь кодом.

Comment: @IgKos пример такого документа покажите...

Comment: Все также как в первом посте, только в отдельных блоках без                 < Data name='gx_media_links'>
            <value>some links 2</value>
        </Data>

Comment: @IgKos Добавил в ответ.

Comment: @andreycha да, вы правы, столкнулся с проблемой двойных кавычек, пока с сотен блоков были только в двух местах и я их просто удалил в оригинале, ибо, в данный момент, осилить CsvHelper и переделать код не смогу. Вам pavelip отдельное огромное спасибо.